# Spring security keycloak adapter bearer configuration

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I have java REST application that I wish to protect by keycloak. I did some tests, application works well with keycloak servlet filter but I'm having issues with spring security adapter.

keycloak.json (values deleted)

```
{
  "realm": "",
  "realm-public-key": "",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": ""
}
```

As visible I need only bearer authorization, If request contains valid token then I expect http 200 if not http 401. I used this xml configuration:

```
<security:global-method-security  jsr250-annotations="enabled"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="keycloakAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint">
            </bean>
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="grantedAuthoritiesMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper">
                <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true"/>
                <property name="prefix" value="ROLE_"/>
            </bean>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter"
                class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter"/>
    <bean id="keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter"
                class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="adapterDeploymentContext" class="org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/keycloak.json" />
    </bean>


    <security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="keycloakAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="stateless">
        <security:custom-filter ref="keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>


        <security:intercept-url pattern="*" access="permitAll()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/protected/*" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>
```

What is really happening? Request is authenticated however after success I'm redirected to '/'. Then I'm authenticated again and again. 
Logs:

```
11:18:36,492 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) /services/protected/getAttributes at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) /services/protected/getAttributes at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) /services/protected/getAttributes at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) /services/protected/getAttributes at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter'
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) adminRequest http://test.srv:8080/core2/services/protected/getAttributes
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) /services/protected/getAttributes at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/login']
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Checking match of request : '/services/protected/getAttributes'; against '/sso/login'
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=Authorization, expectedHeaderValue=null]
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher] (http-0.0.0`enter code here`.0:8080-4) matched
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Request is to process authentication
11:18:36,508 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Attempting Keycloak authentication
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.SpringSecurityRequestAuthenticator] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Completing bearer authentication. Bearer roles: [uma_authorization] 
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) User 'e9ae6919-c0f3-4dcb-96f6-82e3373932e9' invoking 'http://test.srv:8080/core2/services/protected/getAttributes' on client 'mak_test'
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Bearer AUTHENTICATED
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Auth outcome: AUTHENTICATED
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Authentication attempt using org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@65776c48: Principal: e9ae6919-c0f3-4dcb-96f6-82e3373932e9; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@44667d3a; Granted Authorities: ROLE_UMA_AUTHORIZATION
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Using default Url: /
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Redirecting to '/core2/'
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@159e9b90
11:18:36,555 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
11:18:36,570 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-0.0.0.0:8080-4) / at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
```

I'm testing this endpoit by Junit

```
@Test
    public void protectedTest() throws IOException {
        String token = getToken();
        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String url =  server + "/services/protected/getAttributes";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
        Assert.assertEquals(200, con.getResponseCode());
        System.out.print(String.format("Authorized time: %s ms ", (System.currentTimeMillis() - time1)));
    }
```

Endpoint code:

```
@RestController
public class ProtectedService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/services/protected/getAttributes",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_UMA_AUTHORIZATION")
    public GetCustAttrsRes getAttributes() {
        return new GetCustAttrsRes();
    }
}
```

Keycloak server version: 2.1.0.Final

Keycloak related pom part:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was a mistake in my testing code. Method getToken() returns " bearer ". This is acceptable in keycloak filter adapter but NOT in spring security adapter. Right way is "Bearer " and it works in both adapters.

Comment: How do you get the token?